# Swagger/OpenApi Codegen generate request body from xsd

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

We are using swagger-codegen/openapi-codegen for generating our API's.

I want my API to consume `"application/xml"`

and the request body to be generated from xsd scheme.

When i consume `application/json`
my code for post looks like this:

```
parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "Request Object For Adding User"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/User"
```

While in definitions i have

```
definitions:
  User:
    type: "object"
    required:
      - "name"
      - "email"
    properties:
      name:
        type: "string"
        example: "john"
      email:
        type: "string"
        example: "john@gmail.com"
```

Some idea how i can achieve that?